# How to encode an Urdu string in Dart?

Tags: dart

I extract an Urdu text from a web adress. For example, my text is `فروردین`. But when I print it, I see 'ÙØ±ÙØ±Ø¯ÛÙ'. How can I print it correctly?

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart'; 
import 'package:html/parser.dart'; 
import 'package:html/dom.dart';



Future initiate() async {
  var client = Client();
  Response response = await client.get('https://www.varzesh3.com/');

  var document = parse(response.body);
  List<Element> links = document.querySelectorAll('tr.match-date > td.text-center');

  for (var link in links) {
    print(link.text)
    //var bytes = utf8.encode(link.text);
  }
```

Comment: How do you parse the response.body? I can see you are calling a parse() method but I cannot see the implementation. My guess are there are some place where you are not parsing the input with the correct charset.

Comment: @julemand101 I edited my question. This Future works for scrapping and printing English texts. But I don't know how to set it for other languages.

Comment: Again, where are your definition of the parse() method? Please provide a small complete example which shows you problem.

Comment: It's a built_in method in Dart.

Comment: Please give full example which also shows your imports.

Comment: @julemand101 Done.

Comment: Ok, so we agree that "It's a built_in method in Dart" was not true but parse() is a method from the html package. ;)

Comment: What os and shell are you using? I know the Windows cmd.exe has some issues with UTF-8 characters, could that be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the client don't recognize the charset of the page and defaults to latin1. Please take a look at the following code where I force using UTF-8 instead by taking the respond as bytes and convert them to UTF-8 by using the utf8 decoder.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart';

main() async {
  var client = Client();
  Response response = await client.get('https://www.varzesh3.com/');

  var document = parse(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes), encoding: "utf8");
  List<Element> links = document.querySelectorAll(
      'tr.match-date > td.text-center');

  for (var link in links) {
    print(link.text);
  }
}
```